# How to retrieve parameters from a POST request in C#?

Tags: c#, post, parameters

I have a minimal API app with a login form.
How do I retrieve the loginname and password entered by the user?

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("cookie")
    .AddCookie("cookie", options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/login";
    });
builder.Services.AddAuthentication();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/login", GetLogin.Handler);
app.MapPost("/login", PostLogin.Handler);

app.Run();
```

GetLogin.cs: (to show the login form)

```
namespace Server.EndPoints
{
    public static class GetLogin
    {
        public static async Task Handler(string returnUrl, HttpResponse response)
        {
            string html =
                $""""
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>Login</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <form action="/login?returnurl={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(returnUrl)}" method="post">
                            <input value="YourLoginName" type="text" /><br>
                            <input value="YourPassword" type="text" /><br>
                            <input value="Submit" type="submit" />
                        </form>
                    </body>
                </html>
                """";

        response.Headers.ContentType = new string[] { "text/html" };
            await response.WriteAsync(html);
        }
    }
}
```

PostLogin.cs: (to handle the response from the login form)

```
namespace Server.EndPoints
{
    public static class PostLogin
    {
        public static async Task<IResult> Handler(HttpContext context, string returnUrl)
        {
            // How to retrieve the loginname and password for validation?

            return Results.Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

I've been googling literally for hours, but can't find an answer for this.

Comment: You should probably find a tutorial for whatever type of project (template) that you're using. If posting on SO, you should mention what project template you're using in your post.

Comment: You don't. Passwords are never stored or passed to the server. They are hashed using a secure hash function, and the hash is passed. Storing plain-text passwords is a big no-no in security. The user once logged in can be gotten from `HttpContext.Current.User`.

Comment: Tu deschizi eu inchid, As mentioned in my original post I have a minimal api project. Also I have googled for hours and not found anything whatsoever, hence this post.

Comment: Charlieface, when I enter my credentials in the login screen, they somehow need to be passed to the server to be verified. Only when they are successfully verified the user is logged in.
I'm at the point where I typed in my credentials in the login form, which then passes these input fields to the server to be validated. But how do I retrieve these input fields on the server?

Comment: I personally never used the minimal API approach but i guess this is what you are looking for? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/parameter-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: jeb, thanks, that's a helpfull page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.MapPost("/submit", async (HttpContext context) =>
{
    // Accessing form POST values
    var form = await context.Request.ReadFormAsync();
    string name = form["name"];
    string email = form["email"];

    // Do something with the form values

    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Form submitted successfully!");
```

Comment: T. Nielsen, thank you very much, this was what I was looking for!

Comment: @Onno that's great, i'm glad i could help. Please mark it is the answer in that case, if You don't mind, it adds some reputation points back :)